# Explain the default file structure in a newly created AWS Cloud9 environment

Tags: aws-cloud9

I want to understand in which directory I am supposed to create and initialize my Git repository to work with source code.

Whenever I create an AWS Cloud9 environment using the AWS Management Console with all default settings and then open the IDE in the browser, I see the following structure.

```
├── other default Linux folders....
└── home/
    └── ec2-user/
        ├── environment/
        │   ├── .c9/
        │   │   └── <autogenerated_files>
        │   └── README.md
        ├── node_modules/
        ├── package-lock.json
        └── package.json
```

What is the reason of having npm package initialized in `ec2-user/` folder?

The `package.json` has the following content

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "node-cleanup": "^2.1.2",
    "tmp": "^0.0.33"
  }
}
```

Do I need to ignore all of these files and simply create a folder inside `environment/` to initialize my Git repository there? Or can I remove the `ec2-user/` folder entirely and create a new folder to place my files in?